# Where would I find software to design PCBs?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I’ve been looking online for software to design a simple PCB for a project I’m working on; however, when I look it up, all I find are online shops to buy PCB prototypes, not to design them. Are there any website/downloadable free softwares where I could design a PCB file for printing?

Comment: Questions like this are a bit off topic here. Just a hint: Probably you are looking for wrong key words. Search for "EDA schematic and PCB design software"

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sunstone https://www.sunstone.com/ offers free software that ties into their (very very good) PCB fabrication service.   They have 'econo' boards which are specifically targeting the hobby market like you're probably in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the free KiCAD.

You'll find its website through an internet search.

That's one of the most polished and fully-featured of the free schematic capture/PCB layout software tools.

Comment: The question is effectively a "where or what to purchase" question. Also there are multiple possible solutions, none of which may be "correct." Since there cannot be a "correct" answer to the question, it's off-topic. In the early days of the site it was OK to have "list" style questions, where the votes on answers would act as a sort of metric to indicate the best or most favored solution, but AFAIK that's not how the site is moderated any longer.

Comment: The YouTube guy with the bowtie has excellent tutorials on KiCad.